# How to fetch parent url of the current failing url in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am trying to fetch the parent url of the current failing request (for eg consider a travel website ,parent url will be search creteria and current url is selecting flights page).How can we do it .I tried it with putting a if controller after failing url and a beanshell so that it fetches the parent url of all the failings flights request. But what is happening is ,if the current flight request is falining it wont go to the next if controller at all. Execution stops. Can someone guide me with the better way?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all forget about Beanshell, [you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) starting at least from JMeter version 3.1 (for earlier versions it was also recommended, however Groovy engine wasn't included in JMeter distribution)
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the 2nd request
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
       log.info('Previous sampler name: ' + ctx.getPreviousSampler().getName())
       log.info('Previous sampler URL: ' + ctx.getPreviousSampler().getUrl().toString())
   }
   ```
4. That's it, you should see the name of the previous sampler and its URL in the [Log Viewer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) panel and in *jmeter.log* file

   [image]

   You can save the URL into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

   ```
   vars.put('url', ctx.getPreviousSampler().getUrl().toString())
   ```

   once done you will be able to access the value as `${url}` where required.

References:

- `prev` stands for current [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
- `ctx` is a shorthand for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)
- `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)

See JavaDoc for the above classes for description of used functions and [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter.